# How to insert HTML element inside another HTML element in directive template?

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with simple template:

```
restrict: 'E',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {},
template: '<ul></ul>
```

How can I add inside the template li elements dynamically with code in the link function?
My li list is HTML elements:

```
var newElement = $compile("<li><div>my text</div></li>")(scope);
element.append(newElement);
```

This will not add newElement as a child of ul...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element` is not `ul` in your case but your directive wrapper element. You need to find list element first:

```
var newElement = $compile("<li><div>my text</div></li>")(scope);
element.find('ul').append(newElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

A different option would be to replace the directive wrapper element with the directive template

```
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {},
template: '<ul></ul>
```

Then you can just use the original code to append the new element

```
var newElement = $compile("<li><div>my text</div></li>")(scope);
element.append(newElement);
```